# Including a file in JavaScript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I know similar questions have been asked a thousand times before but I get lost in the ECMAScript references and most of the answers are for including in an HTML file, and Webpacker can create some difficulties.

I have about 50 links to maps and other sources that I use in several JavaScript files.

Using webpacker so my JavaScript file is `app/packs/webpacker/olLocationShowMap.js` *(I'm deviating from the current convention by naming folder webpacker instead of javascript.)*

Currently `olLocationShowMap.js` has several hundred lines of definitions for vars that I would like to use in another JavaScript file that is used on a different page in a different model. My approach would be to create a file named `app/packs/webpacker/mapVars.js` and include it in the two other JavaScript files.

Background: the script is called from .html.erb by `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'olLocationShowMap' %>`

How is this done? I tried erb, but the above line fails if the file is named `olLocationShowMap.js.erb`

Some of the shared information:

```
var osmLink = '<a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  esriLink = '<a href="https://www.esri.com/">ESRI</a>',
  mbLink = '<a href="https://mabbox.com/">OpenStreetMap</a>',
 <more of these>

// / URLs for the servers
var osmUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  esriUrl =
    'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServe\
r/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
 <more of these>
```

Comment: Webpacker does not support `.erb` files by default. You need to enable the integration https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/integrations.md#erb.

Comment: @max I had done the two things recommended (and I just reran the command and checked the `webpacker.yml` file, but the call from show.html.erb fails. `http://localhost:3000/locations/164 500 (Internal Server Error)` and `Webpacker can't find olLocationMap.js.erb`. I tried changing the call to `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'olLocationMap.js.erb' %>`